# Bazel incrementality with --define

Tags: bazel

When the value of `--define` is changed, like from `--define=foo=bar` to `--define=foo=qux` , would the build be done incrementally (build only targets that depend on $(foo) ) or causing the entire re-build?

Answer (score 1):

Only the "depending" targets are invalidated by such change. After all it's essentially input/source just like a source file, build description, tool or an environmental variable would be. E.g.:

```
config_setting(
    name = "bar",
    define_values = {
        "bar": "1",
    },
)

cc_binary(
    name = "hello",
    srcs = ["hello.cpp"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "chello",
    srcs = ["hello.c"],
    copts = select(
        {
            ":bar": ["-DBAR"],
            "//conditions:default": [],
        }
    ),
)
```

Only `chello` target gets redone as you manipulate value of `--define bar=...`

Comment: It's worth noting that bazel will have to reanalyze everything though (which could take some time), but only the affected actions will get executed.